# Django: need help in designing relationships between models

Tags: django, django-models

I have an app which allows to associate to each client multiple boards, boards where I can upload files relevant for the client to make decisions about how the website page in question will look.

So the relationships I need to model are:

1. one client, multiple boards;
2. one board, one client;
3. one board, multiple files;

Let's concentrate on the first two

**models.py**

```
class Board(models.Model):
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="Titolo")
    description         = models.TextField()
    files               = models.FileField( null=True, blank=True, upload_to = 'clients_download_area',  verbose_name = 'Client Reserved File')
    date                = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name = 'Data di pubblicazione')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

class Client(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address     = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    boards  = models.ManyToManyField(Board, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Ok, relationship #1 is done. But what if I need to know which client is associated to a board (relationship #2)?

If I set a new field to Board Class

```
class Board(models.Model):
   [...]
   client               = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank = True)
```

of course, when I `makemigrations` Django complains because it does not know what **Client** is, since I define it in the next model.

How can I design this DB?

Thank you in advance for any help you could provide

Comment: ok, but what if I need to get the client associated to a board? Is it possible? even with a different logic.. thank you @guillermochamorro

Comment: Now I'm doubting of my haste comment, given the answers below. Listen to Willem Van Onsem he knows what he's talking about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you *reference* to an identifer (here `Client`), before it is constructed (since `Board` is defined *before* the `Client` class).

Django has some support for this: you can pass *strings* that contain the name of the model. In the same app, you can just use `ClassName`, for another app, you can use `other_app.ClassName`, like the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) says:

> If you need to **create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined**, you can **use the name of the model**, rather than the model
>   object itself:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Car(models.Model):
>     manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
>         'Manufacturer',
>         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
>     )
>     # ...
>
> class Manufacturer(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     pass
> ```

So here you can write it like:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="Titolo")
    description = models.TextField()
    files = models.FileField( null=True, blank=True, upload_to = 'clients_download_area',  verbose_name = 'Client Reserved File')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name = 'Data di pubblicazione')
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        'Client',
        related_name='my_boards'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(Board, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Note however that you already defined a `ManyToManyField` relation from `Client` to `Board`. Although it is possible it is not very common that two such relations exists simultaneously.

If you define a `ForeignKey` relationship from `Board` to `Client`, then Django automatically creates a *reverse* relationship (with the `related_name`), such that `some_client.my_boards`, is a manager of all the related `Board`s.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can pass model class name instead of the class itself:

```
class Board(models.Model):
   [...]    
   client_id = models.ForeignKey('Client', blank=True)
```

Comment: Small remark: in Django, `ForeignKey`s do *not* end with the `_id` suffix, since Django automatically adds a `fieldname_id` attribute that contains the value of the primary key of the referenced object.